# Finding fundamental set of solutions of a given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Suppose that $y_1,y_2$ is a fundamental set of solutions of this equation $t^2y''-3ty'+t^3y=0$ such that $W[y_1,y_2](1)=4$  , Find $W[y_1,y_2](7).$

---

I can't evaluate faundamental solutions.Seems difficult . Don't understand where use this result $W[y_1,y_2](1)=4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$t^2y''-3ty'+t^3y=0$$
$$y''-\dfrac 3ty'+ty=0$$
$$y''+py'+qy=0$$
You can certainly use [Abel's identity:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity)
$$W'+pW=0$$
$$tW'- 3 W=0$$
Where $W$ is the wronskian of the differential equation. You need $W[y_1,y_2](1)=4$ for the constant of integration.

Comment: thank you i understand now

Comment: You're welcome Aritra @AritraRoy